# I want my image in xCode to fade in

Tags: xcode6, fade, duration

I want my image to fade IN, not out.  With this code, it's backwards.  Any help?

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        self.circleOne.alpha = 0.0;

```
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your circleOne has alpha 0(invisible) all you need to do is set the alpha to 1:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
 self.circleOne.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

Edit:

If you want to make a animation before it appears on screen, you can set the alpha to 0 before adding the circleOne the it's parentview.

Assuming that circleOne is an UIImageView it would be like this:

```
circleOne = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName,jpg"]];
circleOne.alpha = 0.0;
[parentView addSubview: circleOne];
//run the animation explained before
```